# Performance loss after computer fell down the stairs

Tags: windows-7

My baby had an accident. After a night-long LAN Party, I've dropped my computer down the stairs! When I popped the case open I saw that my huge video card GTX 260 has got out of her slot and is now loose in the case. I've put it back but then the computer didn't boot up.

I noticed that the motherboard had slid a little to the right so I've loosen all the screws on it an put it back on. still doesn't boot up. I've tried to put the video card in another computer, it worked. so tried another card in. it also worked. I've put my card back in before. the screen hangs on standby for about 10-15 seconds then boot up normally.

the problem is now I experience huge slow down ingame. I've made a benchmark with windows 7 and everything was exactly the same except for videocard that dropped from something like 6.9 to 5.5.

Is there a way I can find what causes the problem ? what should I do to get performance back ? how do I know if I need to change the video card or the motherboard ?

Thanks in advance for your help as I'm in complete distress. Cryin' on the dead body in front of me.

Comment: Poor PC :( You sure your HDD isn't damaged, too?

Comment: Was the computer running when you dropped it?

Comment: @Connor W - it's almost certainly a desktop PC, so no it wouldn't have been running.

Comment: for about a minute there I thought it was your real (human) baby!

Answer (score 3):

Ohh a guessing game, how fun :-)

Check to make sure all of your heatsinks and fans are set properly and operational.  If one of them is no longer connected and working, the video card or cpu may be overheating and dropping its performance to compensate.

[See this link, be glad this isn't still 2001](http://video.google.com/videoplay?docid=3336933539640249505&ei=2ERBS_rgBoyQqALbsLH1Ag&hl=en#)

Answer (score 2):

As well as checking that the HDD isn't damaged you should check that all the memory modules are OK (properly seated and working) as well as the CPU itself, any other expansion cards (network etc.) and the HDD cables (both data and power) as well.

A drop like that will, at the very least, have shaken everything.

The fact that your video card works OK in another machine is encouraging - it implies that the damage isn't total or to everything.

Answer (score 2):

After a serious hit, and you don't get much more serious than falling down the stairs, you need to take the computer back to basics and unplug/replug anything and everything that can be plugged.

This means, hard drive, optical drive, power cables and most importantly - memory.

Also, unfortunately, anything with movable parts could be permanently damaged such as hard drives so - cross your fingers!

Answer (score 1):

One thing you also want to look for are small fractures in the motherboard. These can be insidious as things may work perfectly fine some of the time (when everything lines up correctly) but may fail or malfunction for no apparent reason later.

They're hard to identify and I can't think of a foolproof way to spot them. One thing you might try would be to remove the motherboard **carefully**, and to place it on an anti-static bag. Then carefully inspect the board using a bright light (eg. LED Torch) held at an angle, this may help to reveal the fractures as shadows.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have another computer compatible with your graphics card you should benchmark it there and see if the card is still performing as it should be.

Reseat the memory modules and run **[Memtest86+](http://www.memtest.org/)**.

Run **[HD Tune](http://www.hdtune.com/)** for a hard disk health and error check.

*Both programs are free.*

you may also run **[GeekBench](http://www.primatelabs.ca/geekbench/)** and compare the score with similar systems in their [Result Browser](http://browse.geekbench.ca/).

Comment: If the hard drive is going, then of course try to rescue it (if it has anything important, like your personal files or really hard to get game saves). I'm sure you can find some questions on the topic on SU.